# C# ASP.NET Master Page and ChildPage - Assign strings from Child Page into Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, master-pages, radgrid

Here is the section of my child page file and my master page file respectively. I am going  to pass strName,   from Child page to master page .I would like to access this Master Page variable in child page and assign child page variable to master page on or before the Page Load. I often get the last  selected value but not the current value

For instance , Given the record shows Mary, John , Peter,

if I click Mary , then show none
if I click Peter, show Mary
if I lick John,  show Peter

Would you please suggest and show how to resolve this issue ?

the following is my code

```
   protected void grdNameSelection_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) 
    {
        RadGrid CurrentGrid = (RadGrid)sender;
        GridData GridSource = PageSource.GrdSrcNameSelection;
        String a = GridSource.state.ToString();

        if (e.CommandName == "SelectCurrent")
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem item in CurrentGrid.SelectedItems)
            {

                RowData row = (RowData)GridSource.Current[item.DataSetIndex];
                string Name = row.Name;
            }
        }
    }
 protected void grdCompanySelection_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserSession.Instance.CurrentName= Name ;

        RadGrid CurrentGrid = (RadGrid)sender;
        GridData GridSource = PageSource.GrdSrcCompanySelection;
        CommandButtonDisplay(GridSource, CurrentGrid);

    }
```

Master Page

```
 protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblHeader.Text = UserSession.Instance.CurrentName;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {  ,,,,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately MS hasn't provided a very good way of doing this. You basically have two options.

1. Access the control from the child page and then set whatever value you need (child page is `this` in the example):

   ```
   Label label1 = this.Master.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
   label1.Text = "Hello";
   ```
2. **Preferred** provide some kind of setter on the master page. This is "safer" because the child page doesn't directly manipulate the master's controls.

   ```
    MyType master = this.Master as MyType;
    if(master == null)
       return;

    master.MyProperty = "something";

    // In master page
    public string MyProperty
    {
       get { return label.Text; }
       set { label.Text = value; }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
2nd answer seems to be the best answer

Comment: what is the importance to create the instance for the Master Page ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- probably should be a separate question. Master pages allow for 'templates' and reduces code duplication. You have to cast the `Master` property to your type to access custom methods/properties you define (make them public)